# Adjust so that the table is generated correctly

Tags: r

I'm having a brief problem, see I'm entering `US $` before the numbers however for `NA` values I would like it to be inserted "-" and not `US $NA`. I even did `across(everything(), ~ replace_na(as.character(.), '-'))`, but when I enable this line, the decimal places of the values change and not inserted `US $` before the numbers, so I don't know how to adjust this, any help?

```
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
coef1 = c(445.23231, 1.31231, 6.32323, 1.232),coef2 = c(8.3231, 3.3432, 1.3233, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")


Test %>%
  mutate(sum = rowSums(across(3:last_col()), na.rm = TRUE), 
         #across(everything(), ~ replace_na(as.character(.), '-')),
         across(where(is.numeric), ~sprintf("US $%.2f", .x)))

       date2 Category      coef1    coef2        sum
1 2021-06-30      FDE US $445.23 US $8.32 US $453.56
2 2021-06-30      ABC   US $1.31 US $3.34   US $4.66
3 2021-07-01      FDE   US $6.32 US $1.32   US $7.65
4 2021-07-02      ABC   US $1.23   US $NA   US $1.23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` to insert "-" when values are NA.

```
Test %>%
  mutate(sum = rowSums(across(3:last_col()), na.rm = TRUE), 
         across(where(is.numeric), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), "-", sprintf("US $%.2f", .x))))
#        date2 Category      coef1    coef2        sum
# 1 2021-06-30      FDE US $445.23 US $8.32 US $453.56
# 2 2021-06-30      ABC   US $1.31 US $3.34   US $4.66
# 3 2021-07-01      FDE   US $6.32 US $1.32   US $7.65
# 4 2021-07-02      ABC   US $1.23        -   US $1.23
```